# What is the difference of using :new and new in triggers in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

In example,

I have this trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SAL_REDUCE
BEFORE UPDATE ON DRIVER --or insert--
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(NEW.SAL < 1000) THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'SALARY CANNOT BE REDUCED!!! PAY THEM MORE');
END IF;
END;
/
```

and this trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Salary_check
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Sal, Job ON Emp99
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
Minsal NUMBER;
Maxsal NUMBER;
Salary_out_of_range   EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

/* Retrieve the minimum and maximum salary for the
employee's new job classification from the SALGRADE
table into MINSAL and MAXSAL: */

SELECT Minsal, Maxsal INTO Minsal, Maxsal FROM Salgrade
WHERE Job_classification = :new.Job;
IF (:new.Sal < Minsal OR :new.Sal > Maxsal) THEN
  RAISE Salary_out_of_range;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN Salary_out_of_range THEN
  Raise_application_error (-20300,
     'Salary '||TO_CHAR(:new.Sal)||' out of range for '
     ||'job classification '||:new.Job
     ||' for employee '||:new.Ename);
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  Raise_application_error(-20322,
     'Invalid Job Classification '
     ||:new.Job_classification);
END;
/
```

so, in the second example as you noticed the usage of :new as I described on the headline, and in the first example the usage of new without the colon. what is the difference between these two?

Thanks!

Comment: You use `:new`(with a colon) to reference a pseudo record in a trigger. Referencing `new`(without a colon) will generate an error, unless you have some other object(composite object) named `new`, package for example - bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The first trigger is syntactically incorrect. As already commented by Nicholas, `:new` is required within the body of the trigger.

The only place where `new.` is needed is in the `WHEN` clause of the trigger definition. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SAL_REDUCE
BEFORE UPDATE ON DRIVER --or insert--
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.SAL > 100)
BEGIN
  IF(:NEW.SAL < 1000) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'SALARY CANNOT BE REDUCED!!! PAY THEM MORE');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

In this silly contrived example, the trigger will only fire if `SAL` is over 100.